# Refactoring Suggestion for PagerAdapter implements View.OnClickListener

Tags: android, android-pageradapter, android-event

I have the following code but I'd like to consolidate the View.OnClickListener objects into one function by implementing View.OnClickListener. But When the position of the page keeps changing when the click event happens.
Before refactoring my code looks like this:

```
public class APagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter{
private OnQuoteItemClickListener quoteItemClickListener;
    public APagerAdapter(ArrayList<Quote> list, Context context) {
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;

}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {



    quote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            TextView v = (TextView) view;
            if (quoteItemClickListener != null) {
                quoteItemClickListener.onQuoteClick(position);

            }
            startAction(v, v);
        }
    });


    container.addView(layout);

    return layout;
}

public void setQuoteItemClickListener(OnQuoteItemClickListener listener){
    this.quoteItemClickListener = listener;
}

public interface OnQuoteClickListener{
    void onQuoteClick(int pos);
}
}
```

My refactored code. The position of the item shifts by when the click event happens. I set a global variable for the position as int i to feed into the click event function. I can't understand why the position keeps shifting by one when the click event happens.

```
public class APagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter implements View.OnClickListener{
private OnQuoteItemClickListener quoteItemClickListener;
int i = 0;
public APagerAdapter(ArrayList<Quote> list, Context context) {
    this.list = list;
    this.context = context;

}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
   i = position;
    quote.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       if(v.getTag().equals("quote")){
                startAction(v, i);

        }
    }

public void setQuoteItemClickListener(OnQuoteItemClickListener listener){
    this.quoteItemClickListener = listener;
}
public interface OnQuoteItemClickListener{
    void onQuoteClick(int pos);
}
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: what is difference you saw after refactoring? Can you also share how u are getting quote from the list<Quote>?

Comment: The item is incremented by one. I'm not sure why the global variable of i updated itself as if the next item on the list. How do I feed in the position of the pageradapter to the onClick if the pager implements the OnClickListener interface?